# p:commandButton click updates h:form unwantedly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
    <p:commandButton id="excelAccountLevelOneAccLvl1" ajax="false" icon = "fa fa-fw fa-download" >
                        <f:param name="accountLevelOneFormRequest" value="accountLevelOneFormRequest" />
                        <p:dataExporter type="xlsx" target="baselineOneTable"
                            fileName="#{exportToExcelPageBean.fileName}"
                            postProcessor="#{exportToExcelPageBean.postProcessXLS}" />                              
                    </p:commandButton>
```

On clicking this button, somehow the forms seems to update and it activates the Faces validation and asks me to fill enter the mandatory field values! I can't figure out why! There is not `update` parameter here at all!

Comment: So, this problem disappears when you remove Hibernate, or replace MyFaces by Mojarra, or replace XHTML by JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update is for ajax requests only. You are using ajax="false" which means the commandButton activates a 
full page request. That in turn means that the whole form in which the commandButton is included is 
processed. If you want to avoid this put your commandButton in a separate form.

Comment: So true! Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @Ajachs: Effectively this answer explains the default jsf behaviour. Better to get to grips with it by reading a good tutorial. Helps preventing similar questions in the future.

Comment: You cannot use ajax with p:dataExporter.